# Copy nodes in DOM using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I have an XML file of this Kind :

```
<data>
 <First id="FirstOne">
  <lines id="Lines">
   <Second id= "second" ColorPerVertex='true'></Second>
   <third id="third" color ='true'></third>
  </lines>
 </First>
</data>
```

I was trying to copy all the childnodes of the parentnode - lines.

this is the kind of snippet I tried :

```
var txt=$(xml).find("lines").children();
alert(txt); // to check if it is really does fetch it.
```

it does not output all the children including the attributes of it.

I tried looking into this example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324303/cut-and-paste-moving-nodes-in-the-dom-with-javascript). Even this did not work for me.

is there any way in which I can do it?

Comment: try `console.log(txt)` instead of alert then check the console

Comment: @Joseph : It does fetch it in the Console as required. But why doesnt it alert?

Comment: alert does not provide detailed information. It's only "detailed" when you pass it text. for objects, it's useless. don't debug using alert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2):

---

**jQuery( html [, ownerDocument] )**

`html: A string of HTML to create on the fly. Note that this parses HTML, not XML.`

---

Use [**$.parseXML**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) instead to create the XML-document.

```
var txt=$($.parseXML(xml)).find("lines").children();
```

Comment: Can you please elucidate me as to how this can help me?

Comment: Sorry, My bad. Dint look at 
var txt=$($.parseXML(xml)).find("lines").children();