# How to move all HTML element children to another parent using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-manipulation

Imagine:

```
<div id="old-parent">
    <span>Foo</span>
    <b>Bar</b>
    Hello World
</div>
<div id="new-parent"></div>
```

What JavaScript can be written to move all the child nodes (both elements, and text nodes) from `old-parent` to `new-parent` without jQuery?

I don't care about whitespace between nodes, though I expect to catch the stray `Hello World`, they would need to be migrated as-is too.

**EDIT**

To be clear, I want to end up with:

```
<div id="old-parent"></div>
<div id="new-parent">
    <span>Foo</span>
    <b>Bar</b>
    Hello World
</div>
```

The answer of the question from which this is a proposed duplicate would result in:

```
<div id="new-parent">
    <div id="old-parent">
        <span>Foo</span>
        <b>Bar</b>
        Hello World
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Cut and Paste" - moving nodes in the DOM with Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/324303/cut-and-paste-moving-nodes-in-the-dom-with-javascript)

Comment: @MarcB, this is not a duplicate. The question you link to does not deal with moving _all_ children, nor does any answer on that question address my need to move different types of HTML node (such as text nodes.)

Comment: the answer is exactly what you need. dom is a tree. move one node, all the children of that node move along with it.

Comment: @MarcB sometimes you don't want the parent object in the destination. Consider for example moving all the elements of a TODO list from the 'pending' to 'complete' parent elements.

Answer (score 157, accepted):

Basically, you want to loop through each direct descendent of the old-parent node, and move it to the new parent. Any children of a direct descendent will get moved with it.

```js
var newParent = document.getElementById('new-parent');
var oldParent = document.getElementById('old-parent');

function move() {
  while (oldParent.childNodes.length > 0) {
    newParent.appendChild(oldParent.childNodes[0]);
  }
}
```

```css
#old-parent {
  background-color: red;
}

#new-parent {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="old-parent">
  <span>Foo</span>
  <b>Bar</b> Hello World
</div>
<div id="new-parent"></div>
<br>
<button onclick="move()" id="button">Move childs</button>
```

[External link](http://jsfiddle.net/62f9L/)

Comment: To be really efficient:

`while (oldParent.childNodes.length) {
 newParent.appendChild(oldParent.firstChild);
}`

Comment: Note, that childNodes[] usually contains empty text nodes, too (one for each line break in the source code).

Comment: @Gibolt I'm not sure that's more efficient, but it may be cleaner. I'll run a JSPerf on it and see if there is much difference.

Comment: @Dercsár They aren't technically empty, then ;)

Comment: @Gibolt I created a [JSPerf](http://jsperf.com/childnodes-array-access-vs-firstchild) test and it seems to indicate for me that the array access is faster than calling `firstChild`. The difference is negligible at best. It probably will vary from browser to browser as well. I think `firstChild` is more readable, though.

Comment: `while (oldParent.hasChildNodes()) newParent.appendChild(oldParent.firstChild);` and `while (oldParent.firstChild) newParent.appendChild(oldParent.firstChild);` work 2x faster in Chromium and 6x to 10x faster in Firefox. [Your modified JSPerf](https://jsperf.com/childnodes-array-access-vs-firstchild/2)

Comment: Also worth mentioning, you really should check that `(newParent !== oldParent)`, otherwise you'll get an infinite loop

Comment: @Gibolt That would be impossible unless you are misusing the `id` attribute.

Comment: It might be beneficial to use DocumentFragment https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment and move all elements at once if you are after performance.

Comment: When iterating the child nodes using something like `[].forEach.call(oldParent.childNodes, item => newParent.appendChild(item));` you are changing the length of the child nodes, so it causes an error. The proper solution is moving them like in the snippet of this solution.

Comment: With ```DocumentFragment``` be careful, if you use ```cloneNode```, you'll lose all events attached on nested elements.

Comment: First witch work. Thank you very much. I worked nearly 7 hours to transfer all child elements from a div to another div.

Comment: For me, @user 's comment worked although instead of ```firstChild```, I used ```firstElementChild```.

Answer (score 49):

Modern way:

```js
newParent.append(...oldParent.childNodes);
```

1. `.append` is the replacement for `.appendChild`. The main difference is that it accepts multiple nodes at once and even plain strings, like `.append('hello!')`
2. `oldParent.childNodes` is *iterable* so it can be spread with `...` to become multiple parameters of `.append()`

It's supported by every browser except IE.

Comment: Looks very elegant. I wonder if there's a performance difference to the other answers here.

Comment: If there is it must be minimal. If anything it's faster because it's a single `append`  call instead of many.

Comment: Be warned: not for IE11 (never, probably)

Comment: Nice, but I did some simple tests and `while()` is still slightly faster in Chrome. Don't take my word for it and perform your own tests if possible.

Answer (score 9):

Here's a simple function:

```
function setParent(el, newParent)
{
    newParent.appendChild(el);
}
```

`el`'s `childNodes` are the **elements to be moved,** `newParent` is the **element `el` will be moved to,** so you would execute the function like:

```
var l = document.getElementById('old-parent').childNodes.length;
var a = document.getElementById('old-parent');
var b = document.getElementById('new-parent');
for (var i = l; i >= 0; i--)
{
    setParent(a.childNodes[0], b);
}
```

**[Here is the Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LPz8b/6/)**

Comment: How would you use this with his code? This would move the `old-parent` element too if you passed that as `el`.

Comment: That would render HTML: `<div id="new-parent"><div id="old-parent">...</div></div>`

Comment: That won't work either because as you move the child, the length changes. So, you will end up only moving half of the nodes. You need to iterate backwards, or use a while loop like I did.

Comment: Still won't work. You need to do: `for (var i = l; i >= 0; i--)` or `while (document.getElementById('old-parent').length > 0)`. Also, your demo has errors in it.

Comment: @crush look at edit, sry - `while (document.getElementById('old-parent').length > 0)
{
    setParent(document.getElementById('old-parent')[i], document.getElementById('new-parent'));
}`

Comment: Now you have the same answer as me, except you moved appendChild to a function, which seems pretty unnecessary (no offense). Oh wait, you have an undefined variable `i`...change that to 0, if you are going to use the `while` loop...

Comment: @crush Was rushing, using for loop and a variable, seems different to me!

Comment: That will work. Don't forget to add your `setParent` function in your demo - and update your answer.

Comment: Looking in the demo, I don't see the elements having moved (using dev tools.) Also, you should avoiding looking up the elements by ID so many times. Do that once outside your loop. Also, I think that by looping in reverse, you are reversing the order of the elements.

Comment: @DrewNoakes He just needs to reference element `0` instead of using `i` for the index of the element. Also, he forgot to add his `setParent` function to his demo which is why it isn't working. I agree on the constant ID lookups. The `for` loop of this fashion is basically synonymous to the `while` loop in my example.

Comment: `var l = document.getElementById('old-parent').length;` should be `var l = document.getElementById('old-parent').childNodes.length;`

Comment: @crush I edited my answer with the new fiddle.  Also, there's nothing in your question that says not to reverse the order of elements.

Comment: `a[i], b` should be `a.childNodes[0], b` (use 0 to not reverse the elements)

Comment: Slow down take your time =] Looks good now, and is working. Good job. +1 for fixing your mistakes.

Comment: What's the point? It's better to just use the DOM API directly rather than through this wrapper. It adds nothing of value at all.

Comment: @ZzZombo Unfortunately, I posted this answer six years ago and I don't remember JavaScript, or even understand the terminology you're using, so I can't tell you. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

This is shalow solution - switch nodes ids and change their sequence. If you not use `-` in id's names then you can do this

```js
oldParent.id='xxx';
newParent.id='oldParent';
xxx.id='newParent';
oldParent.parentNode.insertBefore(oldParent,newParent);
```

```css
#newParent { color: red }
```

```html
<div id="oldParent">
    <span>Foo</span>
    <b>Bar</b>
    Hello World
</div>
<div id="newParent"></div>
```

Comment: This isn't moving the children, it's just **swapping** the parents in a 1999-kinda way. If you add more attributes to the oldParent HTML, this will become obvious.

Answer (score -2):

This answer only really works if you don't need to do anything other than transferring the inner code (innerHTML) from one to the other:

```
// Define old parent
var oldParent = document.getElementById('old-parent');

// Define new parent
var newParent = document.getElementById('new-parent');

// Basically takes the inner code of the old, and places it into the new one
newParent.innerHTML = oldParent.innerHTML;

// Delete / Clear the innerHTML / code of the old Parent
oldParent.innerHTML = '';
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This works, though I don't really want to serialise/deserialise via HTML strings. It does work though :)

Comment: It won't copy any of the objects and events attached to the elements

Comment: This regenerate DOM, it dont move existing nodes/events and it is probably way more slow than a loop on all children

Comment: I ran some simple tests and this method is still slower than the accepted answer, and it has disadvantages as already explained.