# move an entire html div from one page to another using jquery

Tags: javascript, html

how can i move an entire html div from one page to another using jquery 
here is an example :

**index.html**

```
  <div id="parent1" class="con">
      <h1>text</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
         consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod t
         empor incididunt ut labore et dolore
        <span class="icon">icon</span>
      </p>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="btn">click me</a>
   </div>
```

**input.html**

```
<div id="parent2" class="con">


</div>
```

I want when I click on the  `btn` I move what is inside `#parent1` to the `#parent2` that is in the `input.html` page

any help please and thank you in advance I have read that question but it didn't help me solve the problem

[How to move all HTML element children to another parent using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20910147/how-to-move-all-html-element-children-to-another-parent-using-javascript)

Comment: You can move only on same file not to another file using jquery

Comment: Its not possible with Javascript.

Comment: You can't really move it. You could use ajax to insert part of your index file into input.html when it loads

Comment: You may find the MDN article [How the Web works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/How_the_Web_works) helpful. It gives an overview _how_ all the parts of serving and rendering a HTML file work.

Comment: @Tigger. Anurag you are taking this literally, he want's to populate a div with other div, it is just so happens that those are in different files. I doubt the OP thinks that client-side JavaScript can change file contents and what's the point in doing so (if this is really the case)?

Comment: @VitaliyTerziev OP clearly stated there there are 2 html files with different names, why should we assume otherwise?

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava, because of Ajax technology?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it will work as your wish.

On 1st Page store data into localStorage variable

```
var page_content = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML;
console.log( page_content );
localStorage.setItem("page_content", page_content );
```

Retrieve on 2nd page

```
document.getElementById("parent2").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("page_content");
console.log( page_content );
```

Check console on 1st page for confirmation data storing successfully.