# moving html chunks from one page to another

Tags: javascript, html

how can i move some html elements from one page to another, I thought JS would do the job if I link both of the html pages to the same Js page but I was wrong I feel It's easy to do but something is missing I can't do it I have searched here on stack overflow and google and I didn't find something that would solve the problem

here is an example:

**index.html**

```
<div id="parent1" class="container">
  <h1>text</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
    <span class="icon">icon</span></p>
</div>
<a href="#" class="btn">click me</a>
```

I want when I click on the  `btn` I move what is inside `#parent1` to the `#parent2` that is in the `input.html` page

**input.html**

```
<div id="parent2" class="con">


</div>
```

questions I have read and didn't solve the problem : ["Cut and Paste" - moving nodes in the DOM with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324303/cut-and-paste-moving-nodes-in-the-dom-with-javascript)

[How to move all HTML element children to another parent using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20910147/how-to-move-all-html-element-children-to-another-parent-using-javascript)

and that questions helped me a little bit but it uses the XML and Jquery and I'm not familiar with them is there any easier solution and thank you in advance

Comment: Other than the above approach of opening a separate window, you can't accomplish this with javascript alone. You'd be better off doing this server side

Comment: you'll have to automatically open th second page with `JavaScript` to get control over it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using jQuery, which makes this super easy with `jQuery.load()`, then I would do like:

```js
//<![CDATA[
var doc, bod, get, M, T, I, S, Q, loadIt; // for use on other loads
addEventListener('load', function(){
doc = document; bod = doc.body;
get = function(url, success, context){
  var x = new XMLHttpRequest;
  var c = context || this;
  x.open('GET', url);
  x.onload = function(){
    if(success)success.call(c, x.responseText);
  }
  x.send();
}
M = function(tag){
  return doc.createElement(tag);
}
T = function(tag){
  return doc.getElementsByTagName(tag);
}
I = function(id){
  return doc.getElementById(id);
}
S = function(selector, within){
  var w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelector(selector);
}
Q = function(selector, within){
  var w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
loadIt = function(url, selector, loadedFunc){
  var d = M('div'), s;
  d.style.display = 'none'; bod.appendChild(d);
  get(url, function(r){
    d.innerHTML = s = r.replace(/(\n|\r)+|^.*<body>|<\/body>.*$/g, '');
    if(typeof selector === 'string')s = S(selector).outerHTML;
    loadedFunc(s); bod.removeChild(d);
  });
}
loadIt('yourURLHere.html', '#someId', function(res){
  someOtherElement.innerHTML = res;
});
});
//]]>
```

The `loadIt` function should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it will work as your wish.

On 1st Page store data into localStorage variable

```
var page_content = document.getElementById("parent1").innerHTML;
console.log( page_content );
localStorage.setItem("page_content", page_content );
```

Retrieve 1st page data on 2nd page

```
document.getElementById("parent2").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("page_content");
console.log( page_content );
```

Open console for confirmation data storing successfully on 1st page.